# Kan liftings and projective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, enriched-category-theory, dg-categories, projective-varieties

Regard the following two bicategories:

- $\operatorname{dg-\mathcal{B}imod}$, with objects dg categories, and morphisms categories from $C$ to $D$ being the categories of $C$-$D$-bimodules. Composition is given by the dg tensor product. Note that this might be considered as the bicategory of Chain-complex-enriched profunctors/ relators (see [Coend Calculus](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02503)), so the machinery developed in this paper should (as chain complexes form a Bénabou-cosmos) show that every 1-morphism in this category has both a left and a right adjoint, and Right Kan Liftings exist here
- $\mathcal{V}ar$, with objects smooth projective varieties and morphism categories from $X$ to $Y$ the derived categories $D^b (X \times Y)$, as considered [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.2052). The 1-morphisms here encode kernels for Fourier-Mukai-Transformations. Using the Serre kernel, it is shown in that paper that every 1-morphism in this bicategory has a left and a right adjoint.

These bicategories are very closely related; it was shown e.g. by Toen that if one takes the dg enhancements of the derived categories $D^b_{dg}(X)$, $D^b_{dg}(Y)$, then the dg functors between those are in one-to-one correspondence with the elements of $D^b(X \times Y)$, to name just one similarity. Therefore, I would suspect that also the second category possesses Right Kan Liftings, but I am not sure how to construct them (as already the proof that the Serre kernel lets us construct adjoints there is very nontrivial).

Is this indeed true? How are they constructed? And most importantly (as from the fact that $\mathcal{V}ar$ has adjoints, a lot can be deduced about Grothendieck duality etc.) do they also have interesting uses in the study of smooth projective varieties, or can their construction even be extended to more general schemes?

Comment: Years ago I thought for a long time about the possibility to use profunctors to describe Fourier-Mukai theory: this question looks very natural to me. I would start with this question: dg-functors $D(X)\to D(Y)$ correspond to objects of $D(X\times Y)$. Is this also a functor, and not only a correspondence on objects? An equivalence of categories? What about dg-profunctors?

Comment: @Fosco I also think this is the right question to ask. For reference, this is statement 8.15 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408337), checking functoriality seems to boil down to going through [here](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/schwede/stablemodelcats.pdf) (referenced in 8.9). Essentially, the latter paper proves that certain stable model categories have a compact generator, and one would have to show that this assignment even works in a functorial way. I'll need a bit more time to check if this actually works out.